# QGIS: Preserve layer names when loading raster

Tags: qgis, raster, r

I have a raster with 81 bands. The format is `.gri` with an ENVI header file `.hdr`.

Band names are stored together with other information in the header file:

> ENVI
>   description = { CARI Carter Carter2 Carter3 Carter4 Carter5
>   Carter6 CI CI2 ClAInt CRI1 CRI2 CRI3 CRI4 Datt Datt2 Datt4 Datt5 Datt6
>   DD DDn DWSI4 DWSI5 EVI GDVI_2 GDVI_3 GDVI_4 GI Gitelson Gitelson2 GMI1
>   GMI2 Green.NDVI Maccioni MCARI MCARI2 mND705 mNDVI MPRI MSAVI mSR mSR2
>   mSR705 MTCI MTVI NDVI NDVI2 NDVI3 NPCI OSAVI PARS PRI PRI_norm PRI.CI2
>   PSRI PSSR PSND SPVI.1 PWI RDVI REP_Li SAVI SIPI SPVI.2 SR SR1 SR2 SR3
>   SR4 SR5 SR6 SR7 SR8 SRPI TCARI TCARI2 TGI TVI Vogelmann Vogelmann2
>   Vogelmann4 }

When reading the file into QGIS, I just get "Band 01", "Band 02" etc. when using the "Identify" tool.

When reading the file into R, layer names are preserved. Here not the `.hdr` file is taken but the corresponding `.grd` file for reading layer names.

I am wondering where QGIS reads/tries to read layer names from if not from the `.hdr` file (which is required otherwise QGIS cannot open the file at all)?

Get the [data from here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B67PGH7aAAJMMVZXeGFvd29OQ1E/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Probably QGIS does not read band names at all but just lists them in the order they appear in the image file. Format info at http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html does not say anything about band names.

Comment: You can use a python script to read **hdr** file for creating a dictionary with the help of **re** (regex) python module. Afterward, it's easy to select corresponding band, by using true band name as a key, for selecting adequate number band inside **gdal_translate** command to split it. By the way, supposed duplicate question is unanswered and I think that you can ask for reopening your question.